# Monorepo PNPM with nuxt 2 and nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, pnpm

I have been working with monorepo for some months using Nuxt-2 for all my packages, but now, I want to create a new package using Nuxt-3!

I searched about hoist feature, but I can't make this work!

I searched and I found a similar problem in this repository https://github.com/Suniron/monorepo-nuxt2-nuxt3-problem, I have the same problem and the same structure.

Use a lot configurations in .npmrc.